# Decoded bytestring value by .decode() provides string value of bytes of initial string if I try to wrap it in list/dict and etc

Tags: python, byte, decode

in Python, I have a bytestring, which I decoded by .decode() and shows me the right string value. But when I trying to put it in a list, or dictionary, it puts bytestring(as a str slass) into list:

```py
byte_data = b'901\x00LHD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
decoded_str = byte_data.decode()
print(type(decoded_str))
print(decoded_str)
print([byte_data.decode()])
```

results:

```
<class 'str'>
901LHD
['901\x00LHD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00']
```

I want:

['901LHD']

I tried .decode('utf-8'), or any other decode techniques, it didn't work

Comment: Your string contains null bytes which don't show when you print it, but they are part of the string nevertheless. In the last case, you get the `_repr_` of the string when printing the list, which will show them

Answer (score 0):

I changed the answer (due to the comments).

You can use the `re` module to achieve this.

```py
import re

byte_data = b'901\x00LHD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
decoded_str = byte_data.decode()
new = re.sub('\x00','',decoded_str)

print([new])
```

This replaces the `\x00` pattern with `''` and produces the desired outcome.

result:

```
['901LHD']
```

Comment: There are null bytes inside the string, not only at the end.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille good point.  have modified to `strip()`.

Comment: It won't remove from the middle of the string either...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, again, you are correct.  The best way that i found was to remove the `\x00` pattern using the `re` module to eliminate the middle null byte.

Comment: You don't need the `re` module at all. `decoded_str = byte_data.replace( b'\x00',b'').decode()` should do the trick as well…